# Different qtcreator behavior in compiling code

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cross-compiling, uwebsockets

I'm trying to compile this code using Qtcreator:

```
uWS::App().ws<PerSocketData>("/*", {
        /* Settings */
        .compression = uWS::DEDICATED_COMPRESSOR_3KB,
        .maxPayloadLength = 16 * 1024 * 1024,
        .idleTimeout = 10,
        .maxBackpressure = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        /* Handlers */
        .upgrade = nullptr,
        .open = [](auto *ws) {
            /* Let's make every connection subscribe to the "broadcast" topic */
            ws->subscribe("broadcast");
        },
        .message = [](auto *ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
            /* Exit gracefully if we get a closedown message (ASAN debug) */
            if (message == "closedown") {
               /* Bye bye */
               us_listen_socket_close(0, global_listen_socket);
               ws->close();
            }

            /* Simply broadcast every single message we get */
            ws->publish("broadcast", message, opCode, true);
        },
        .drain = [](auto */*ws*/) {
            /* Check getBufferedAmount here */
        },
        .ping = [](auto */*ws*/, std::string_view) {

        },
        .pong = [](auto */*ws*/, std::string_view) {

        },
        .close = [](auto */*ws*/, int /*code*/, std::string_view /*message*/) {
            /* We automatically unsubscribe from any topic here */
        }
    }).listen(9001, [](auto *listen_socket) {
        global_listen_socket = listen_socket;
        if (listen_socket) {
            std::cout << "Listening on port " << 9001 << std::endl;
        }
    }).run();
```

and get this error:

```
cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'uWS::TemplatedApp<false>::WebSocketBehaviormanagement::Websocket::Runner()::PerSocketData.
```

But I compile same code using same compiler (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++) in command line successfully.
What is wrong?
Anyway I change my code to this and it compiled fine in Qtcreator too.

```
uWS::TemplatedApp<false>::WebSocketBehavior<PerSocketData> wsb = {
            /* Settings */
            .compression = uWS::SHARED_COMPRESSOR,
            .maxPayloadLength = 16 * 1024,
            .idleTimeout = 10,
            .maxBackpressure = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
            /* Handlers */
            .upgrade = nullptr,
            .open = [=](auto* ws) {
                //std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
                is_there_stream = true;
                //g_ws = ws;
            },
            .message = [](auto* ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
                //ws->send(message, opCode, true);
                std::cout << message << std::endl;
            },
            .drain = [](auto*/*ws*/) {
                /* Check ws->getBufferedAmount() here */
            },
//            .ping = [](auto*/*ws*/) {
//                /* Not implemented yet */
//            },
//            .pong = [](auto*/*ws*/) {
//                /* Not implemented yet */
//            },
            .close = [=](auto*/*ws*/, int /*code*/, std::string_view /*message*/) {
                /* You may access ws->getUserData() here */
                is_there_stream = false;
            }
        };

        uWS::App().ws<PerSocketData>("/*", std::move(wsb)).get("/restart", [](auto* res, auto* req) {
            //protocol->Restart();
        }).listen(PORT, [](auto* listen_socket) {
            if (listen_socket) {
                std::cout << "Listening on port " << PORT << std::endl;
            }
        }).run();
```

There is no problem in compiling right now but I don't know what happened. Plus The Qtcreator getting errors from lines that I commented them (ping/pong).

```
error: could not convert '<lambda closure object>management::Websocket::Runner()::<lambda(auto:14*)>{}' from 'management::Websocket::Runner()::<lambda(auto:14*)>' to 'uWS::MoveOnlyFunction<void(uWS::WebSocket<false, true, management::Websocket::Runner()::PerSocketData>*, std::basic_string_view<char>)>' {aka 'ofats::any_invocable<void(uWS::WebSocket<false, true, management::Websocket::Runner()::PerSocketData>*, std::basic_string_view<char>)>'}
```

while there are similar code like this (drain).

Why the same compiler shows these different behaviors?
Please help me to understand this.

PS: full similar code is [here](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/blob/master/examples/BroadcastingEchoServer.cpp).

Comment: Looks like you might be building with the C++ version set to a different version than the one you are using over the commandline. The issue is probably in whatever makefile you are using (QMake, CMake, QBS?). Make sure you enable support for the minimal required C++ version.

Comment: I changed -std from gnu++1z (used in qtcreator) to c++2a (used by make) and nothing changed.

Comment: In the "Compile Output" panel you can see exactly which compiler is invoked and what arguments are passed, maybe that will help you figure out the difference...